# Limits of integral: $\iint_D e^{y/x}\,dx\,dy$, where $D : 1 ≤ x ≤ 2 − y , |xy| ≤ 1$.

Tags: integration

What are the limits of the integral:
$\iint_D e^{y/x}\,dx\,dy$, where $D : 1 ≤ x ≤ 2 − y , \lvert xy\rvert ≤ 1$.

I have previously done integrals such as:
$\iint_D\sqrt{y}\sin(xy)\,dx\,dy$, where $D : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 , 0 ≤ y ≤ \frac{\pi}{2}$
, where $x$/$y$ max/min are more easily derived (at least to my capabilities).

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, the secret is in *drawing the picture*.

Try drawing the lines $x=1$ and $x=2-y$; for the other, note that $\lvert xy\rvert\leq 1$ is equivalent to $x\lvert y\rvert\leq 1$, since $x\geq 1$; this is equivalent to $\lvert y\rvert\leq\frac{1}{x}$, since $x\neq 0$. But this, in turn, is the same as 
$$
-\frac{1}{x}\leq y\leq\frac{1}{x}.
$$
Try plotting these four boundary curves, and see if you can pick out what the region is.  The trick, of course, is to get constant bounds for one of the variables (whichever you like), then bounds for the second that depend on the first.

**Edit:**
The region in question looks like this:

[image: Plot region]

(Ignore the slightly un-shaded part in the right corner; it should be shaded as well).  Here, the line is $x=2-y$ (or, equivalently, $y=2-x$), and the bottom curve is $y=-\frac{1}{x}$. So, for a given $x$-coordinate, which $y$-coordinates are possible?

Comment: So if I have the curves;
 x=1
 y=x-2
 y=-1/x
 y=1/x

I could attempt to determine where they intersect? Doing something like:

1. x=1 inserted into the equations gives two intersects: (1,1) and (1,-1)

2. y=-1/x and y=1/x do not intersect 

3. y=-1/x and y=x-2 intersect when x=1 which gives (1,1) 

4. y=1/x and y=x-2 which intersects when x=1+-sqrt(2) (which I get by 1/x=x-2), this would give me the two intersects of: (-0.6,-2.4) and (2.4,0.4) of which only the latter is relevant due to the limits resented earlier (x>=1)

So this will give me the limits: xmin=1, xmax=2.4 and ymin=-1, ymax=1.

Comment: Does the above look correct? Also, how does one go about to do an empty line? It looks really messy and I'd like edit it :>.

Comment: No, that is not right.  Think about it: if you integrate on the limits you have presented, _you are integrating over a rectangle_. The region in question is definitely not a rectangle.  See the update to my answer.

Comment: I can see what you mean! I am attempting to use the 'triplequad' command with MATLAB (which may not be ideal for this particular integral as it integrates over rectangular boxes) and it does not accept variable limits. Could one maybe change the variables so we get 0≤u≤1 or something like that?

Comment: A differentiable transformation could, at best, get you to a triangle (I believe); you would still need variable limits.

Comment: @Soakr If you insist on doing this by computer, you could also define a piecewise function which takes the correct value in the shaded region, and is 0 outside of it; then, you can integrate on any rectangle which contains the region in question.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time and input Nicholas. Since it is a requisite to do this integration by MATLAB I will look into the 'shadow method'.

Answer (score 0):

$\large\mbox{Without pictures !!!}.$

$\displaystyle{%
D
\equiv
\left\{\vphantom{\Large A}\left(x, y\right)
\quad\ni\quad
1\ \leq\ x\ \leq\ 2 − y,\quad
\left\vert xy\right\vert\ \leq\ 1\right\}}$.

\begin{equation}
\int\int_{D}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,
\Theta\left(x - 1\right)\Theta\left(2 - y - x\right)\Theta\left(1 - \left\vert xy\right\vert\right)
\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

It's convenient to integrate first over $y$ since it appears in two of the $\theta\,$'s functions. Also, it's clear that $x \geq 1$ such that we get rid of the correspondent $\Theta\left(x - 1\right)$ function and $-1/x < y < 1/x < 0$:

\begin{equation}
\int\int_{D}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
=
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\,\int_{-1/x}^{1/x}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,
\Theta\left(2 - y - x\right)\,{\rm d}y
=
\left.
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\,\int_{-1/x}^{1/x}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,{\rm d}y
\right\vert_{y\ <\ 2 - x}
\end{equation}

However
$$
\left.\int_{-1/x}^{1/x}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,{\rm d}y
\right\vert_{y\ <\ 2 - x \atop {\vphantom{\Large A}x\ >\ 1}}
=
\left\{%
\begin{array}{lcl}
0\,,
& \mbox{if}\quad &
{2 - x < -\,{1 \over x}
 \atop
 \Longrightarrow\ x > 1 + \sqrt{2\,}}
\\[3mm]------&-&--------
\\[3mm]
\int_{-1/x}^{2 - x}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,{\rm d}y\,,
&
\mbox{if}\quad
&
{-\,{1 \over x} <2 - x < {1 \over x}
 \atop
 \Longrightarrow\ x < 1 + \sqrt{2\,}}
\\[3mm]------&-&--------
\\[3mm]
\int_{-1/x}^{1/x}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,{\rm d}y\,,
&
\mbox{if}\quad
&
{2 - x > {1 \over x}
 \atop
 \not\exists\ x > 1\ \mbox{that satisfies it.}}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
\int\int_{D}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
&=
\int_{1}^{1 + \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,}}\,{\rm d}x\,
\int_{-1/x}^{2 - x}{\rm e}^{y/x}\,{\rm d}y
=
\int_{1}^{1 + \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,}}
x\left({\rm e}^{2/x - 1} - {\rm e}^{-1/x^{2}}\right)
\,{\rm d}x
\\[3mm]&=
\int^{1}_{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,} - 1}
\left({\rm e}^{2x - 1} - {\rm e}^{-x^{2}}\right)
\,{{\rm d}x \over x^{3}}
\end{align}

I guess the reader can take it from here.